# jQuery 'clone' script with other variables doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery

I have 'cloned' a script, except for the variables the script is exactly the same as the original! But it just doesn't entirely work. it get stuck at:

```
if(validConnection=="")
{
   $('#UsernameConnection').css('border-color','#00ff00');
   $('.ErrorUsernameConnection').text('');
   checkUsername1 = true;
}
```

(*the rest of the code is below*)

I have been checking if I made some mistake in changing the varables but they all seem to match properly. What is wrong? How comes it work fine just with different variables and not this time???

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="Connection">   
<div class="Connection">
    Connection
    <a href="#" id="HideConnection"><strong>×</strong></a>  
</div>

<?php connection(); ?>

<div class="formConnection">
    <form method="POST" autocomplete="off" name="Connection">
        <label for="Connection">Username:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="UsernameConnection" id="UsernameConnection"/><br/>
        <span class="ErrorUsernameConnection"></span><br/>
        <label for="Connection">Password:</label><br/>
        <input type="password" name="PasswordConnection" id="PasswordConnection"/>
        <span class="ErrorPasswordConnection"></span><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/><label>Remember me</label><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="Connection" value="Log In" id="Connection" class="LogIn"/>       
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the php:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['UsernameConnection']))
    {
        $Username1 = $_POST['UsernameConnection'];

        if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ]{1,}[._-\s]?)+[a-zA-Z0-9àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ]{1,}$/",$Username1))
        {
            echo "";
        }else
        {
            echo "Invalid";
        }
    }       
?>
```

and JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var checkUsername1 = false;


    $('#UsernameConnection').keyup(function(){

        var Username1 = $('#UsernameConnection').val();

        if(Username1=="")
        {   
            $('#UsernameConnection').css('border-color','red');
            $('.ErrorUsernameConnection').text('Error message 1');
            checkUsername1 = "Username empty";
        }else
        {
            $.post('fonctions/validUsernameConnection.php',{Username1:Username1},function(validConnection)
            {
                $('.ErrorUsernameConnection').text(validConnection);

                if(validConnection=="")
                {
                    $('#UsernameConnection').css('border-color','#00ff00');
                    $('.ErrorUsernameConnection').text('');
                    checkUsername1 = true;
                }else
                {
                    $('#UsernameConnection').css('border-color','orange');
                    checkUsername1 = "Username Invalid";
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

PS: I'm a little bit lost with all the stack's sites so forgive me if this isn't the right one to post this =/

Comment: what doesn't work? any errors in firebug? why do you get stuck at this particular if?

Comment: Is the path `'fonctions/validUsernameConnection.php'` correct (typo?)? Any error messages in the console? Value of `validConnection`?

Comment: @h4b0, Well, if $_POST['usernameConnection'] doesn't math the preg_match in the php file, the script doesn't recognize it. No errors in firebug. I don't know why =/

Comment: @Andreas, yep path is correct. No errors. validConnection values are the echos in the php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problems seems to be with this line

```
$.post('fonctions/validUsernameConnection.php',{Username1:Username1},
function(validConnection)
```

In your PHP you should check for $_POST['Username1']  instead of $_POST['UsernameConnection']

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I thought the php file should call the input in the HTML page but it actually should call the var in the jQuery file, right?

Comment: The AJAX call from jQuery sends the variable to the PHP script, so yeah this is where you need to be careful for future AJAX scripts :-)

Comment: Just to make this clear, because I think it's been badly explained, your PHP needs to be checking for the parameter(s) with the name(s) defined by the key(s) in the object literal passed as the `data` argument of `$.post()`. In your case, you have an object with a key of `Username1` and a value equal to the value of your `Username1` variable, so in your PHP your request will have a parameter called `Username1`. If your key had been `UsernameConnection` (`{UsernameConnection: Username1}`), then the request parameter would have also been called `UsernameConnection`.

Comment: Thanks for the better explaination, simple things are sometimes hard to explain